# Automatical consecutive numbering of footnotes in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Is it possible in Latex to make footnotes without providing the number manually but instead let LaTeX number them consecutively throughout the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\footnote[Number]{Text}
```

`Number` is optional. Don't use it and LaTeX will do what you want.

Comment: Oh, I tried that but like this: \footnote[]{Text} instead of \footnote{Text}